# Pattern matching and polluting the namespace

Tags: pattern-matching, packages, scoping

I am building a library. Inside of `BeginPackage` environment there is a function

```
RhoSeries`ImposeSymmetryOnCoefficient[coefficient_[a_,b_,c_], symmetry_] := Switch[symmetry,
    Ansatz`SymmetryST, coefficient @@ Insert[Sort[{a,b}],c,3],
    Ansatz`SymmetrySU, coefficient @@ Insert[Sort[{a,c}],b,2],
    Ansatz`SymmetryTU, coefficient @@ Insert[Sort[{b,c}],a,1],
    Ansatz`SymmetrySTU, coefficient @@ Sort[{a,b,c}],
    _, coefficient @ {a,b,c}]
```

I am getting `a::shdw` error about it appearing both in `` SMatrix` ``  and `` Global` ``  scopes. However no prior use of `a` is in my code, not to mention the definition (it occurs solely in the pattern matching. Same with `b` and `c`

The editor insistently colors every occurrence of these variables.
However, out of

```
Definition[a], Definition[SMatrix`a], Definition[Global`a]
```

all return `Null` (tho editor colors the second one as defined. All of them also return atomic expression themselves, no definitions.

Is it real? Am I really adding unnecessary stuff to the scope? Is frontend delusional? Shall I change the name in pattern to something like `aButDefinedOnlyInScopeOfThisLibraryToAvoidNameCollision` and do that for any pattern reference?

Also I failed to do any kind of more minimal example, so that's the actual code I'm working with.

Comment: Can you provide the shortest segment of code that causes the problem?  I am unable to reproduce with the code you have given.

Comment: I think if you expose your function names in the `BeginPackage` context like `ClearAll[yourFn]` and then adding ```Begin["`Private`"]``` before the definitions, will likely solve your problem (don't forget to `End[]` after definitions end).

Comment: Just as a side note the minimal example can be demonstrated by executing ```f[a_] := a; BeginPackage["temp`"];``` in one cell and `g[a_] := a; EndPackage[];` in another.